# Rewrite MySQL query to MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb

i really need little bit of help,i am new to MongoDB, is it possible to join collection and to rewrite following query to MongoDB, or if it is not possible, how can i realise this one query? Thanks

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
    b.id,
    b.id_pol AS vrsta_pola,
    b.id_dxzavljanstvo AS drzavljanstvo,
    o.naziv AS opstina,
    bol.naziv AS bolnica,
    b.id_odeljenje AS odeljenje_prijema,
    b.datum_prijema,
    b.id_uputna_dijagnoza AS uputna_dijagnoza,
    b.id_osnovni_uzzok_hospitalizacije AS osnovni_uzrok_hospitalizacije,
    b.datum_ispisa,
    b.bx_dana_lezanja,
    b.id_odeljenje_otpust AS odeljenje_otpust,
    b.id_vrsta_otpusta,
    b.id_obdukovan,
    b.id_spoljni_uzzok_povrede AS spoljni_uzzok_povrede
FROM bol_rac_fl b
LEFT JOIN bolnica bol ON b.idbolnica = bol.id_bolnica
LEFT JOIN opstina o ON b.id_opstina = o.id_opstina
WHERE b.id_opstina = 70220
```

I read that it is not possible to join collection , and it work with lookup, but i don't understand how is possible to get similar result such as MySQL will give back after execution of this query?

Comment: it's almost near impossible to understand what you want. Can you provide input, output and exactly what you want?

Comment: [start here](http://www.querymongo.com/)

Comment: @AlexL it's not possible to convert query, because it works with only one table, when i delete other tables and convert result in MongoDB query, than it not work, but again and that is ok, because i need resutl for join collections

Comment: @MikeTung sorry, i will provide better explenation, i made mistake, i copied query without join tables, sorry please

Comment: What you are doing violates the way MongoDB operates. Be sure to add indexes to the joined tables and the link provided by @AlexL is a good starting point.

Comment: I would not recommend QueryMongo as a good example of MongoDB queries; this site pre-dates the Aggregation Framework and is using the `group()` operator which is deprecated as at MongoDB 3.4. Rather than asking "how should I translate this SQL query", you should be thinking "how should I best transform my data model for MongoDB". A helpful starting point would be the [Data Modeling Introduction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) in the MongoDB manual.